# Remove n characters from console

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, d

I'm writing a program in D that doesn't need a GUI. I remember that in C++, there was a way to remove a number of characters from console/terminal, but I don't know how to do this in D.
How do I remove a number of characters from the console/terminal?

Comment: you can use the `readln` function to get a line then slice some characters off.... what else do you need though, there's a lot of different ways to do it.

Comment: Is it from your input or from your output?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove the typed characters from the console so that if the user typed `hello world`, you could alter it so that it then showed `hello w` on the console instead of `hello world`?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "removing characters". Show a before+after example of what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This didn't fit into a comment and I think it's what you are referring to)

Do you mean [getchar](https://dlang.org/library/core/stdc/stdio/getchar.html)? You have direct access to the entire standard C library in D. For example have a look at this simple script:

```d
void main()
{
    import core.stdc.stdio : getchar;
    foreach(i; 0..3)
        getchar();

    import std.stdio;
    writeln(readln());
}
```

When you compile & execute this script (e.g. here with `rdmd`)

```
echo "Hello world" | rdmd main.d
```

it would print:

```
lo world
```

But I have to agree with Adam that just slicing `readln` is easier and looks nicer ;-)

Comment: That is what I wanted, but this removes them from the start, but I want to remove them from the end.   P.S: sorry for the very late reply.

Comment: If you want to remove them from the end, you must likely have to read the entire input and then slice it  as the comments on your question point out.